# Prevent action in TListView's context menu when in edit mode

Tags: listview, contextmenu, c++builder

I'm using C++Builder XE6 to write a VCL application that contains a `TListView` with an associated `TPopupMenu` context menu.

The `TListView` has `ViewStyle`=`vsReport` and `ReadOnly`=`false`. The associated context menu contains a 'Delete' menu item with `ShortCut`=`Del`.

The 'Delete' menu item has the following `OnClick` event handler:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Delete1Click (TObject *Sender)
{
    ListView1->DeleteSelected();
}
```

The 'Delete' menu item is enabled/disabled in the `OnPopup` event handler of the context menu:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::PopupMenu1Popup (TObject *Sender)
{
    Delete1->Enabled = (ListView1->SelCount > 0);
}
```

When I select an item in the list view and press the <kbd>Del</kbd> key on the keyboard, the `Delete1Click()` event handler is invoked and the item is deleted, as expected.

However, if the list view item is in edit mode and I press the <kbd>Del</kbd> key, the `Delete1Click()` event handler is also invoked, deleting the item. The keypress is not sent to the edit box in the list view.

I tried to fix this by modifying the `OnPopup` event handler of the context menu as follows:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::PopupMenu1Popup (TObject *Sender)
{
    Delete1->Enabled = (ListView1->SelCount > 0 && !ListView1->IsEditing());
}
```

This prevents the deletion of the list view item, but the keypress is still not sent to the edit box in the list view.

When the list view item is in edit mode, the <kbd>Del</kbd> keypress should be handled by the edit box of the list view instead of invoking the `Delete1Click()` event handler.

How do I achieve this?

I don't want to change the shortcut for the 'Delete' menu item, to something like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code handles the Del keypress in both circumstances, without removing the menu item shortcut. When the list view is not in edit mode, `DeleteSelected()` is called to delete the selected items in the list view. When the list view is in edit mode (i.e. an item is being edited), the code simulates a <kbd>Del</kbd> keypress in the edit box of the list view, using `SendMessage()`.

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Delete1Click (TObject *Sender)
{
    if (ListView1->IsEditing()) // Check if list view item is being edited.
    {
        HWND Edit = ListView_GetEditControl(ListView1->Handle); // Get handle to edit window.

        if (Edit)
        {
            UINT Scan = MapVirtualKey(VK_DELETE, MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC);  // Get scan code of Del key.

            SendMessage(Edit, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_DELETE, 0x00000001 | Scan << 16);  // Simulate Del keypress in edit window.
            SendMessage(Edit, WM_KEYUP,   VK_DELETE, 0xC0000001 | Scan << 16);
        }
    }
    else
        ListView1->DeleteSelected();    // Delete selected items in list view.
}

void __fastcall TForm1::PopupMenu1Popup (TObject *Sender)
{
    Delete1->Enabled = (ListView1->SelCount > 0);
}
```

See the documentation for [`WM_KEYDOWN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-keydown) and [`WM_KEYUP`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-keyup) for a description of the bits used in the `lparam` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

To overcome your problem, you need to clear the menu item's shortcut when editing a list item, by adding `OnEditing` and `OnEdited` event handlers to the `TListView`.

```
void __fastcall TForm3::ListView1Editing(TObject *Sender, TListItem *Item, bool &AllowEdit)
{
if(Delete1->ShortCut != NULL) //added
    {

    shortCut = Delete1->ShortCut; //added
    Delete1->ShortCut = NULL;
    }
}
```

Pressing the keyboard <kbd>Del</kbd> key will act as it should while you are editing, when finished editing you can reinstate the shortcut like this:

```
void __fastcall TForm3::ListView1Edited(TObject *Sender, TListItem *Item, UnicodeString &S)
{
//  omit ->  Delete1->ShortCut = TextToShortCut("Del") ; 
//  replace with

Delete1->ShortCut = shortCut;
}
```

Adding these two event handlers work fine in XE7, so you should have no problem with XE6.

You could also, while you are at it, store the menu item's shortcut in a `TShortCut`, then restore from that for each menu item with a shortcut that you are having issues with.

Edit: as a workaround for the ESC problem, adding an OnContextPopup could be used to reinstate the shortcut if the short cut was removed from Delete1

Updated answer to reflect changes

Add a TShortCut shortCut variable to your form.

```
void __fastcall TForm3::ListView1ContextPopup(TObject *Sender, TPoint &MousePos, bool &Handled)

    {
    if(shortCut != 0)
        {
        Delete1->ShortCut = shortCut;
        shortCut = NULL;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The user can cancel the editing by pressing the keyboard Esc key, in which case `TListView` doesn't trigger the `OnEdited` event handler. That would leave the menu item's shortcut cleared. As a result, any keyboard Del keypress will be ignored until an item is actually edited.

Comment: @MartinNijhoff `TListView` does not provide any event for a cancel, so you will have to subclass the `TListView` and handle the `CN_NOTIFY` message directly, looking for the `LVN_ENDLABELEDIT` notification. In the provided `NMLVDISPINFO`, its `item.pszText` field will be `nil` on a cancel. `TListView` triggers the `OnEdited` event in response to that notification only if the `pszText` is not `nil`. Oddly, `TTreeView` has an `OnCancelEdit` event, but they never applied that same logic to `TListView`, even though it is implemented in the same unit as `TTreeView`

Comment: @MartinNijhoff I have opened a ticket with Embarcaadero now: [RSP-39355: Add OnCancelEdit event to TListView](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-39355)

Comment: @MartinNijhoff  Updated answer to handle ESC key workaround using ContextPopup event handler if you had not already come up with a solution to overcome the limitation.

Comment: @RemyLebeau It's odd the `OnCancelEdit` event was overlooked with `T(Custom)ListView`. If the `OnEdited` event would also be triggered on a cancel, it would have been fine too. Thanks for your reply and opening a ticket with Embarcadero.

Comment: @OldTimerLearningNewTricks The workaround to restore the shortcut in the `OnPopup` event handler only works when either the list view is right-clicked or another shortcut key is pressed. It will not work for a Del keypress. I'm not near a computer until Monday, but I think another workaround could be to check `IsEditing()` in `Delete1Click()` and sending a Del keypress to the list view's edit box. I will check on Monday.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I also find it odd that, even in the latest version of Delphi/C++Builder, `TListView` still doesn't include a `vsTile` option for the `ViewStyle` property. Tile view has been around for many years, and implementation is relatively simple. Maybe worth opening a ticket with Embarcadero for that too?

Comment: @MartinNijhoff [RSP-39374: Add Tile View support to TListView](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-39374)

Comment: @Remy - I am trying to work out how to implement CN_Notify in a sub classed ListView, component, I have implemented a MESSAGE_MAP that works to get the keys pressed while in the edit box of the ListView but does not capture the Del, or ESC keys. I have MESSAGE void __fastcall CNNotify(Winapi::Messages::TWMNotify &Message); declared and the code to read the plvdi->item.pszText; but cannot get the code to fire, I am almost sure I have the code right but not there yet, any idea how to fire the event so I can step through, I may not be articulating this well but not sure how too.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for opening the second ticket with Embarcadero.

Comment: @OldTimerLearningNewTricks See my answer for a workaround that doesn't require clearing/restoring the menu item shortcut.

Comment: @OldTimerLearningNewTricks BTW, how did you format the word 'Del' in your answer, so that it looks like a keystroke?

Comment: Used the  Vcl.Menus.TextToShortCut(System::UnicodeString Text) this converts 'Del' to a TShortCut see https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Representing_Keys_and_Shortcuts as for your answer, good stuff I knew there would be a a better way, I am still interested to see if I can get an OnCancelEdit event happening using the CN_Notify that @Remy suggested, may have to ask a question about it, I have most of the work done for it (I think) just need to work out how to fire the event in a VCL_MESSAGE_MAP if that is where I need to do it.

Comment: @OldTimerLearningNewTricks I don't mean formatting the shortcut, but the formatting of the word 'Del' in the text 'Pressing the keyboard Del key will act as...' in your answer. How did you format the text 'Del' to look like a keyboard key?

Comment: @OldTimerLearningNewTricks Nevermind, found it; use the <kbd></kbd> tags.

Comment: @OldTimerLearningNewTricks you didn't show the MESSAGE_MAP code that is not working for you, so noone can tell you what wrong with it.

Comment: @Remy, MESSAGE_MAP code i have is VCL_MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_NOTIFY, TWMNotify, CNNotify); -- MESSAGE void __fastcall CNNotify(Winapi::Messages::TWMNotify &Message); I just now had it working where pressing the ESC key while editing fired the event and showed that item.pszText "" I will post a question and show my code there

Comment: @OldTimerLearningNewTricks inside your ListView class, your `MESSAGE_MAP` needs to handle `CN_NOTIFY` not `WM_NOTIFY`, as I originally stated further above.