# Sub classing a TListView relating to question asked 'Prevent action in TListView's context menu when in edit mode'

Tags: listview, contextmenu, c++builder

Relating to [Prevent action in TListView's context menu when in edit mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73646707/), I'm having an issue reading the value of `plvdi->item.pszText` in a `CNNotify()` event. This value should be `nil` if the edit is cancelled. I tried a few conversions, but no luck. I must be doing something wrong. See the code below.

Everything works, except for comparing the `pszText` value.

.cpp

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "TCustomListView.h"
#pragma package(smart_init)
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// ValidCtrCheck is used to assure that the components created do not have
// any pure virtual functions.
//

static inline void ValidCtrCheck(TCustomListView1 *)
{
    new TCustomListView1(NULL);
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TCustomListView1::TCustomListView1(TComponent* Owner)
    : TListView(Owner)
{
    cancel = false;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TCustomListView1::WMGetDlgCode(TMessage &msg)
{
    TCustomListView::Dispatch(&msg);
    msg.Result |= WM_CHAR;
    //To Do
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TCustomListView1::CNNotify(Winapi::Messages::TWMNotify &Message)
{
    TListView::Dispatch(&Message);
    Message.Result |= LVN_ENDLABELEDIT;

    NMLVDISPINFO* plvdi = (NMLVDISPINFO*)Message.NMHdr;

    if(plvdi->item.pszText == NULL  ) ----->> ??? what am i doing wrong here
    {
        if(FOnEditCancel && IsEditing())
        {
            cancel = true;
            FOnEditCancel(this, this->Selected, cancel);
            cancel = false;
        }
    }
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
namespace Tcustomlistview
{
    void __fastcall PACKAGE Register()
    {
        TComponentClass classes[1] = {__classid(TCustomListView1)};
        RegisterComponents(L"Samples", classes, 0);
    }
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

.h

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#ifndef TCustomListViewH
#define TCustomListViewH
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <System.SysUtils.hpp>
#include <System.Classes.hpp>
#include <Vcl.ComCtrls.hpp>
#include <Vcl.Controls.hpp>

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
typedef void __fastcall (__closure *TOnEditCancel)(TObject* Sender, TListItem* item, bool cancelled);

class PACKAGE TCustomListView1 : public TListView
{
private:
    TOnEditCancel FOnEditCancel;
    bool cancel;

    MESSAGE void __fastcall WMGetDlgCode(TMessage &msg);
    MESSAGE void __fastcall CNNotify(Winapi::Messages::TWMNotify &Message);

    BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP
        VCL_MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_GETDLGCODE, TMessage, WMGetDlgCode)
        VCL_MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_NOTIFY, TWMNotify, CNNotify);
    END_MESSAGE_MAP(inherited);

protected:

public:
    __fastcall TCustomListView1(TComponent* Owner);

__published:
    __property TOnEditCancel OnEditCancel = {read = FOnEditCancel, write = FOnEditCancel};
};
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#endif
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of issues with your code.

- `TCustomListView1` is not a good name for your component. Use something more meaningful.
- Your component doesn't need the `cancel` member at all, so get rid of it.  You could just hard-code the `cancelled` parameter of the `OnEditCancel` event instead. However, that event really should not have a `cancelled` parameter to begin with.  In which case, removing that parameter, you can then make use of one of the existing ListView event types that matches your remaining parameters, such as `TLVNotifyEvent`.
- `WM_CHAR` is a window message identifier, it is not a valid flag that you can add to the return value of the `WM_GETDLGCODE` message.  You meant to use the `DLGC_WANTCHARS` flag instead, which will enable your control to receive `WM_CHAR` messages.
- `LVN_ENDLABELEDIT` is a window message identifier, it is not a valid flag that you can add to the return value of the `CN_NOTIFY` message.  You need to check if the `Message.NMHdr->code` field matches `LVN_ENDLABELEDIT` and then process the `Message.NMHdr` field accordingly.
- you are handling the wrong message in your `MESSAGE_MAP`. You are catching `WM_NOTIFY` messages that are sent from the ListView's header control to the ListView. You need to instead catch `CN_NOTIFY` messages, which are `WM_NOTIFY` messages that the ListView sends to its parent window and are then reflected back to the ListView as `CN_NOTIFY`. The VCL does this reflection to allow components to be self-contained and process their own notifications.

With that said, try something more like this instead:

TMyListViewEx.cpp

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "MyListViewEx.h"
#pragma package(smart_init)
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// ValidCtrCheck is used to assure that the components created do not have
// any pure virtual functions.
//

static inline void ValidCtrCheck(TMyListViewEx *)
{
    new TMyListViewEx(NULL);
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TMyListViewEx::TMyListViewEx(TComponent* Owner)
    : TListView(Owner)
{
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TMyListViewEx::WMGetDlgCode(TMessage &msg)
{
    TListView::Dispatch(&msg);
    msg.Result |= DLGC_WANTCHARS; // TODO
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TMyListViewEx::CNNotify(Winapi::Messages::TWMNotify &Message)
{
    TListView::Dispatch(&Message);

    if (Message.NMHdr->code == LVN_ENDLABELEDITA ||
        Message.NMHdr->code == LVN_ENDLABELEDITW)
    {
        NMLVDISPINFO *plvdi = reinterpret_cast<NMLVDISPINFO*>(Message.NMHdr);

        if ((plvdi->item.pszText == NULL) &&
            (plvdi->item.iItem != -1) &&
            (FOnCancelEdit != NULL))
        {
            // ideally, you should be using TCustomListView::GetItem(LVITEM)
            // to determine the TListItem affected, but that method is private
            // and not accessible to descendants, which is all the more reason
            // why Embarcadero needs to fix this in the native TListView instead...

            TListItem *item;
            if (plvdi->item.mask & LVIF_PARAM)
                item = reinterpret_cast<TListItem*>(plvdi->item.lParam);
            else // TODO: handle OwnerData=true ...    
                item = this->Items->Item[plvdi->item.iItem];

            FOnCancelEdit(this, item);
        }
    }
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
namespace Tmylistviewex
{
    void __fastcall PACKAGE Register()
    {
        TComponentClass classes[1] = {__classid(TMyListViewEx)};
        RegisterComponents(L"Samples", classes, 0);
    }
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

TMyListViewEx.h

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#ifndef TMyListViewExH
#define TMyListViewExH
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <System.SysUtils.hpp>
#include <System.Classes.hpp>
#include <Vcl.ComCtrls.hpp>
#include <Vcl.Controls.hpp>

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class PACKAGE TMyListViewEx : public TListView
{
private:
    TLVNotifyEvent FOnCancelEdit;

    MESSAGE void __fastcall WMGetDlgCode(TMessage &msg);
    MESSAGE void __fastcall CNNotify(Winapi::Messages::TWMNotify &Message);

    BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP
        VCL_MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_GETDLGCODE, TMessage, WMGetDlgCode)
        VCL_MESSAGE_HANDLER(CN_NOTIFY, TWMNotify, CNNotify)
    END_MESSAGE_MAP(TListView);

protected:

public:
    __fastcall TMyListViewEx(TComponent* Owner);

__published:
    __property TLVNotifyEvent OnCancelEdit = {read = FOnCancelEdit, write = FOnCancelEdit};
};
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#endif
```

Comment: The WM_CHAR was originally WM_WANTCHARS I think I changed it when trying things that did not work.

Comment: Unfortunately the CNNotfy code does not work, when I ESC from the edit box I do not get past, if (Message.Msg == LVN_ENDLABELEDITA || Message.Msg == LVN_ENDLABELEDITW) when debugging, also if I try to compile with LPNMLVDISPINFO I get an undefined symbol error.  item = this->Items[plvdi->item.iItem]; also causes an error - E2034 Cannot convert 'TListItems' to 'TListItem *' when I added a .msg return value that allowed me to step through the code.

Comment: "*when I ESC from the edit box I do not get past, `if (Message.Msg == LVN_ENDLABELEDITA || Message.Msg == LVN_ENDLABELEDITW)` when debugging*" - fixed. `Message.Msg` would always be `CN_NOTIFY`, it is `Message.NMHdr->code` instead that would be `LVN_ENDLABELEDIT`. "*if I try to compile with `LPNMLVDISPINFO` I get an undefined symbol error*" - fixed. "*`item = this->Items[plvdi->item.iItem];` also causes an error*" - fixed.

Comment: if (Message.NMHdr->code == LVN_ENDLABELEDITA ||
  Message.NMHdr->code == LVN_ENDLABELEDITW) does not work for me, if I change == to |= for the first LVN I can get it to pass through but when ESC is pressed and I step through to the plvdi->item.pszText == NULL check, pszText is "" and plvdi->item.iItem is not -1 so should execute the code in the if statement, but it does not, I am sure it's not the -1 check as it shows a number like 'iItem 1275145858 (0x4C012E82)' in the watch list so I am guessing it is the check for a NULL value

Comment: @OldTimerLearningNewTricks "*If I change `==` to `|=` ... I can get it to pass through*" - of course, because you are allowing EVERY notification to pass through, which is wrong. The `==` is required to let ONLY `LVN_ENDLABELEDIT` to pass through. "*`pszText` is `""` ... so should execute the code in the `if` statement*" - incorrect, because `""` and `NULL` are different values. Only `NULL` should be allowed to pass through. "*it shows a number like 'iItem 1275145858 (0x4C012E82)'*" - because you are allowing the wrong notifications to pass through, so you are acting on the wrong data.

Comment: @OldTimerLearningNewTricks I see real the problem now. You are catching the wrong message to begin with. You need to catch `CN_NOTIFY` not `WM_NOTIFY`. I fixed my example.

Comment: as always, did not see the forest for the trees, works fine now, thanks again.