# ListView_SetView(..,..) not working for a sub classed TlistView is there a way to do this

Tags: listview, c++builder, vcl

Relating to [Sub classing a TListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73696210/sub-classing-a-tlistview-relating-to-question-asked-prevent-action-in-tlistview) relates also to [Prevent action in TListView's context menu when in edit mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73646707/prevent-action-in-tlistviews-context-menu-when-in-edit-mode)

My subclassed ListView captures the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key (with Remy's help) and now I managed to capture the <kbd>Del</kbd> key when editing, without the side effects of having a menu item's shortcut preventing the <kbd>Del</kbd> key from working in the ListView's edit control.

Calling `ListView_SetView(ListViewEx1->Handle, LV_VIEW_TILE);` works fine on  `TListView`, but not in my `TListViewEx`. Any ideas would be great. - FIXED

.cpp of TListViewEx

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <vcl.h>

#pragma hdrstop

#include "TListViewEx.h"
#pragma package(smart_init)
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// ValidCtrCheck is used to assure that the components created do not have
// any pure virtual functions.
//

static inline void ValidCtrCheck(TListViewEx *)
{
    new TListViewEx(NULL);
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TListViewEx::TListViewEx(TComponent* Owner)
    : TListView(Owner)
{

}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TListViewEx::Click()
    {
    TListView::Click();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TListViewEx::WMGetDlgCode(TMessage &msg)
    {
    TCustomListView::Dispatch(&msg);
    msg.Result |= DLGC_WANTCHARS;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TListViewEx::CNKeyDown(TMessage &Message)
    {
    if (Message.WParam == VK_DELETE)
        {
        if(FOnWantEditEvent)
            {
            FEdit = ListView_GetEditControl(Handle);
            OnWantEditEvent(this, FKey);
            }
        }
    TListView::Dispatch(&Message);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TListViewEx::SetView(int view)
    {
    ListView_SetView(Handle, view);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TListViewEx::CNNotify(Winapi::Messages::TWMNotify &Message)
    {
//    TListView::Dispatch(&Message);
    TListView::Dispatch(&Message);

    if (Message.NMHdr->code == LVN_ENDLABELEDITA || Message.NMHdr->code == LVN_ENDLABELEDITW)
        {

        NMLVDISPINFO *plvdi = reinterpret_cast<NMLVDISPINFO*>(Message.NMHdr);

        if ((plvdi->item.pszText == NULL) && (plvdi->item.iItem != -1) && (FOnEditCancel != NULL))
            {
            // ideally, you should be using TCustomListView::GetItem(LVITEM)
            // to determine the TListItem affected, but that method is private
            // and not accessible to descendants, which is all the more reason
            // why Embarcadero needs to fix this in the native TListView instead...

            TListItem *item;
            if (plvdi->item.mask & LVIF_PARAM)
                item = reinterpret_cast<TListItem*>(plvdi->item.lParam);
            else // TODO: handle OwnerData=true ...
                item = this->Items->Item[plvdi->item.iItem];

            FOnEditCancel(this, item);
            }
        }
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
namespace Tlistviewex
{
    void __fastcall PACKAGE Register()
    {
        TComponentClass classes[1] = {__classid(TListViewEx)};
        RegisterComponents(L"Samples", classes, 0);
    }
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

.h

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#ifndef TListViewExH
#define TListViewExH
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <System.SysUtils.hpp>
#include <System.Classes.hpp>
#include <Vcl.ComCtrls.hpp>
#include <Vcl.Controls.hpp>

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
typedef void __fastcall (__closure *TOnEditCancel)(TObject* Sender, TListItem* item);
typedef void __fastcall (__closure *TOnWantEditEvent)(TObject* Sender, WORD &Key);


class PACKAGE TListViewEx : public TListView
    {
    private:
        TOnEditCancel FOnEditCancel;
        TOnWantEditEvent FOnWantEditEvent;
        HWND FEdit;

        MESSAGE void __fastcall WMGetDlgCode(TMessage &msg);
        MESSAGE void __fastcall CNNotify(Winapi::Messages::TWMNotify &Message);
        MESSAGE void __fastcall CNKeyDown(TMessage &Message);

        BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP
            VCL_MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_GETDLGCODE, TMessage, WMGetDlgCode)
            VCL_MESSAGE_HANDLER(CN_NOTIFY, TWMNotify, CNNotify);
            VCL_MESSAGE_HANDLER(CN_KEYDOWN, TMessage, CNKeyDown);
        END_MESSAGE_MAP(TListView);


    protected:
        DYNAMIC void __fastcall Click();

    public:
        __property HWND Edit = {read = FEdit};
        __fastcall TListViewEx(TComponent* Owner);
        void __fastcall SetView(int view);

    __published:
        __property TOnEditCancel OnEditCancel = {read = FOnEditCancel, write = FOnEditCancel};
        __property TOnWantEditEvent OnWantEditEvent = {read = FOnWantEditEvent, write = FOnWantEditEvent};
    };
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#endif
```

TForm implementation of `FOnWantEditEvent`, based on code by Martin Nijhoff:

.cpp

```
void __fastcall TForm3::ListViewEx1WantEditEvent(TObject *Sender, Word &Key)
    {
    switch(Key)
        {
        case VK_DELETE:
            {
            if(ListViewEx1->Edit)
                {
                UINT Scan = MapVirtualKey(VK_DELETE, MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC);  // Get scan code of Del key.
    
                SendMessage(ListViewEx1->Edit, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_DELETE, 0x00000001 | Scan << 16);  // Simulate Del keypress in edit window.
                SendMessage(ListViewEx1->Edit, WM_KEYUP,   VK_DELETE, 0xC0000001 | Scan << 16);
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------    
void __fastcall TForm3::Delete1Click(TObject *Sender)
    {
    if(!ListViewEx1->IsEditing())
        ListViewEx1->DeleteSelected();

    ViewTile();
    }
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work". What exactly is not working for you? Please be more specific.  One issue I see is if your ListView ever needs to recreate its main `HWND` at runtime, you will lose your custom Tile View setting. Your `SetView()` method would need to cache the input value in a member variable, and then your ListView would need to override the virtual `CreateParams()` method to re-apply the cached view. See how the standard `TListView` internally manages its `ViewStyle` property.

Comment: Also, on a separate note, why is your `OnWantEditEvent` event passing an `HWND*` pointer instead of the `HWND` itself? You don't want the event handler to *change* the `HWND`, so it shoudn't be passed by pointer. Or, for that matter, you don't even need to pass the `HWND` in the event at all since it is already exposed vie the public `Edit` property instead. Personally, I would just get rid of the event altogether, and move the  `SendMessage()` code directly inside the ListView's `CN_KEYDOWN` handler.

Comment: @Remy. ListView now works but, it always did, the problem was that the TListViewEx width was not wide enough to accommodate tile width so items were arranged to look like a vsList.

Comment: @Remy, thanks for pointing out that the Edit is a public property so do not need to pass a HWND, (Fixed) but my intent for the event was to be able to respond to the keys being pressed, in this case for testing purpose it is wired only for the Delete key so the code I have is fit for the purpose and should remain outside the TListViewEx component, I will add a Key parameter to the event if that's ok to do

Comment: @Remy, added the Key param, works fine - fixed code.

Comment: It seems like you are just recreating the existing `OnKey...` events.

Comment: @Remy, yes it does but the problem that Martin Nijhoff was having is that the popup menu intercepted the Del key and stopped it working on the Edit control, OnWantEditEvent allows the code in the event handler to solve the problem but only in the case where you have a menu item that causes this particular side effect.  I found that other keys were not being processed by the Edit of the ListView, this is the reasoning why the Key parameter is there, hope that makes sense.  Cheers

Comment: @MartinNijhoff This could be of interest to you.

Comment: I think you are tackling this problem from the wrong approach. You should read [A Key’s Odyssey – the path of a keystroke message through the VCL](https://web.archive.org/web/20170528152626/https://edn.embarcadero.com/article/38447), it may give you some ideas of how to efficiently intercept keys in your ListView, and/or how to bypass the menu processing while the ListView is in edit mode. I find it very unlikely that the VCL authors didn't already encounter this issue and account for it. `TListView` is not the only VCL component that has a nested editor.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248060/discussion-between-oldtimerlearningnewtricks-and-remy-lebeau).

Answer (score 0):

TListView is **not** the culprit where pressing <kbd>Del</kbd> or any of the other keyboard keys <kbd>A</kbd> through <kbd>Z</kbd> key in the Edit box of a list view item, it is an unintended consequence in an action by the Aplications processing its message queue.

However, TMenuItem does play a roll in this issue, the TMenuItem ShortCut property list is filled with what appears to be the valid keys and combination of keys allowed but, for some reason, it allows a short cut key consisting of single alpha character keys and other keys not intended to be used without a TShiftState key like <kbd>Del</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd> and so on.

[image: Popup menu item with single letter shortcut]

What appears to be happening is that the Applications message queue receives a CNKeyDown message, it then calls the IsMenuKey which asks the control's popup menu if it wants to handle the key, if it does, IsShortCut method is called, and fires the OnShortcut event which should **NOT** have been called because the shortcut key assigned was not intended to be used as a valid shortcut key.

I believe this problem exists in all versions of C++ Builder, the only real way around this problem is to make sure that shortcut keys are selected from the TMenuItem's Shortcut property list.

My tests confirm that a single character <kbd>A</kbd> as well as <kbd>Del</kbd> keys press in a TListView Edit control was intercepted by TAplication which eventually fired the Click() event of the TMenuItem assigned the short cut 'A', the consequences of this can be varied and unintentional and could be devastating in a critical Database type operation especially when the intent of the menu item is to carry out a delete operation without confirmation.

This is surely a bug that needs to be looked at by Embarcadero

Comment: @Remy, is this something you could make a bug report?